# Using dbus-send to call GetAll

Tags: dbus

I tried my luck with:

```
  dbus-send --system --print-reply  \   
     --dest=org.freedesktop.UDisks \
      /org/freedesktop/UIDisks/devices/md0 \
      org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll \
      string:""
```

If I'm using d-free and send ""
as parameter to GetAll I get a long list of output

Trying the code above just gives an error:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetAll" with signature "s" on
interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
```

So I'm doing something wrong, but I've no idea what's wrong. I searched for a solution but did not come up with a decent solution. Maybe it's to trivial, but I have no idea....

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify interface name as a parameter to GetAll. This example works for me (I have UDisks2 instead of UDisks but otherwise it's similar):

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply \
   --dest=org.freedesktop.UDisks2 \ 
   /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/loop0 
   org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll 
   string:"org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block"
```

Comment: Sorry if I give in an empty string in d-feet I get:{'DeviceAutomountHint': '',
 'DeviceBlockSize': 512L,
 'DeviceDetectionTime': 1405083881L,
 'DeviceFile': '/dev/md0',
 'DeviceFileById': ['/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-d56d4165:72b8959a:ea459adc:678b0998',
                    '/dev/disk/by-uuid/0bfac438-3d04-4d4e-a71c-2f4a3e63a8e9'],
 'DeviceFileByPath': [],
 'DeviceFilePresentation': '/dev/md0',
 'DeviceIsDrive': True,
 'DeviceIsLinuxDmmp': False,
 'DeviceIsLinuxDmmpComponent': False,
 'DeviceIsLinuxLoop': False,
 'DeviceIsLinuxLvm2LV': False,
 'DeviceIsLinuxLvm2PV': False,
....

Comment: So there must be a a awy to really GetAll Properties at once.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried my luck with:
>
> ```
> dbus-send --system --print-reply  \   
>    --dest=org.freedesktop.UDisks \
>     /org/freedesktop/UIDisks/devices/md0 \
>     org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll \
>     string:""
> ```

You have a typo in the object path: you put `UIDisks` instead of `UDisks`. Fixing that should fix your error.

---

Addressing your comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24710221/2931197) about getting all properties at once, the [D-Bus specification](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-properties) doesn’t specify that `GetAll` should accept an empty string for its `interface_name` argument, so it’s a bug if any services *do* accept this. Instead, you must call `GetAll` once for each of the interfaces on the object.

The easiest way of doing this is to use a higher-level D-Bus utility, like [`gdbus`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus.html) or [D-Feet](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DFeet) (as you were trying). `dbus-send` is designed for simple, low-level interaction with D-Bus services.

```
$ gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.UDisks2 --object-path /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda1 --only-properties
node /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda1 {
  interface org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Partition {
    properties:
      readonly u Number = 1;
      …
  };
  interface org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem {
    properties:
      readonly aay MountPoints = [b'/boot/efi'];
  };
  …
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After all this years, I finally get around this and found something.
Yes, sometimes it takes some time

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply \--dest=org.freedesktop.UDisks2 \
/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda1 \
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll \
string:"org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem"
```

Works, kind of ot get the Properties of at least the Filesystem interface.

Just took me another few hours to figure out this dbus-send stuff.

Answer (score 0):

> Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetAll" with signature "s" on
>   interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist

I have similar problem, I run d-feet, introspect interface, and find out,
that I should write not "full/path/to/object", but just "/object",
in your case not "/org/freedesktop/UIDisks/devices/md0", but "/md0".

If this not help, try compare all parameters in dbus call with what d-feet
show, I'm sure you find you problem.